# stopping windows service in service client architected

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, windows-services

I've just been working on a system that uses the service-client architecture.
In fact, the core part of the system is a windows service that is called and connected  by clients .
Not to optimise the queries is the big problem of this system and That's why the service stops throughout the day
And Also System operation stops.
I have no time for optimizing the queries in a short term so I'm looking for a solution to prevent stopping windows service like this.
 Consider,The Windows service is meant the self hosted wcf.
Are there any solution in the wcf settings ?

thanks

Comment: What is the reason for service fault? Unhandled exception when SQL query gets timeout or some other random thing?

Comment: Best guess is that you are failing to dispose the connections, causing the service to run out of RAM and shut down. But you would need to post an example of the query to be sure.

Comment: Look for available RAM and CPU when service stops. If RAM then there is memory leak or memory is not released but if CPU utilization is problem then you have to think of optimizing operations.

Comment: There is no error based on timeout 
The error is out of memory
I guess because of the wrong queries,
A large amount of data is transferred from the core to the client
And 
This large amount of data make the service stop

Comment: I will check ram and cpu and will 
I'll let you know thanks

Comment: WCF, like most things network related, will automatically close idle connections.  You can increase the timeout but doing so may be a bad design decision

Comment: there is no problem with cpu and ram the problem is with windows kernel